# Cannot Delete an alias from the KeyStore

Tags: java, android

I am using a `KeyStore` (java.security.KeyStore) in my application.
There are scenarios that I need to delete an alias from the keystore and I am doing that with the following line:

> mKeystore.deleteEntry(alias);

If I close after that the application with 'Force Stop' then when I launch again the application I can see that the entry is **not** deleted and **still exists**! If I don't force stop, then it is deleted (until the force stop).

Can anyone figure why I can't delete an entry from the keystore?

Comment: Do you call store() after deleteEntry() ?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek No, this was probably the problem, please answer this thread so I'll set it as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To flush the updated KeyStore to permanent storage, you probably need to call `mKeystore.store()` after `mKeystore.deleteEntry(alias)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling `Keystore.store()` throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/33770972/31629.)

Answer (score 0):

Calling store(...) after deleting an alias works for me:

```
try (FileOutputStream storeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storePath)) 
{
  keyStore.store(storeOutputStream, pwd);
}
```