# Cannot Delete an alias from the KeyStore - keyStore.store throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android

I have the same problem mentioned in [Cannot Delete an alias from the KeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17770615/234). The solution to that question is "call the .store() method on your keyStore to flush the changes" which seems fine.

My problem is, I'm using AndroidKeyStore, which doesn't seem to support the operation. My code is as follows:

```
public static void resetKeyStore() {
    KeyStore keyStore;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);

        ArrayList<String> toDelete = new ArrayList<>();

        Enumeration<String> e = keyStore.aliases();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()){
            toDelete.add(e.nextElement());
        }

        for(String s : toDelete) {
            keyStore.deleteEntry(s);
        }
        // keyStore.store(null);

    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {           
        Log.wtf(TAG, e);
    }
}
```

If I don't have the call to `keyStore.store(null)`, then this function exits successfully, but there are still some keys in the key store.

If I put the call in, then it throws this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineStore(KeyStoreSpi.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.security.KeyStore.store(KeyStore.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mycompany.myapp.LocalKeyStore.resetKeyStore(LocalKeyStore.java:235)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @Orion, were you able to determine a solution for this issue? I'm experiencing the same situation as you. Also, do you recall what device you were experiencing this issue with? For me, it seems that this code fails when running on a Nexus 5X but works if I test with a Nexus 6P. Both phones are running 6.0.1 so I'm wondering if there are some hardware differences that might be affecting functionality?

Comment: Seeing the same thing. On some devices, you can delete an alias but then checking via `containsAlias()` shows that the delete didn't work (perhaps because the store needs to be saved). There's no mention of it in https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore#store(java.security.KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter) but calling the `store(null)` method definitely throws a `UnsupportedOperationException`.